# Strip carriage returns / line feeds from database records before they are written to csv

Tags: python, sql, csv, row, carriage-return

I have the following code that reads lines from a database and writes the matching results to a csv file.  The problem I am running into is there are occasionally carriage returns / line feeds in some of the fields in different rows which cause the csv file to be unusable because there are bogus rows.

For example, here is a sample of what happens when there are carriage returns / line feeds in the SQL data and the affect it has on the file. ... Sample content of messed up file:

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|val
ue 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|va
lue 4|value 5
```

Here is the code that writes the results of a SQL query to the output file.  What I am trying to do is strip any results that have carriage returns / line feeds.

```
    '''
    While loop to read each row.  if compares row[2] (updated) against the last record processed
    '''
    latest = params #Declare 'latest' variable for consumption by while loop
    while row:
        if row[2] > latest:
            latest = row[2]
        logger.debug("[%s] - Writing row %s", correlationId, row)
        writer.writerow(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    logger.info("[%s] - last letter date %s " % (correlationId, lastProcessed))
    lastProcessedLog = open(LAST_PROCESSED_LOGFILE , 'wt')
    lastProcessedString = str(latest)
    lastProcessedString = lastProcessedString[0:19]
    lastProcessedLog.write(lastProcessedString)
    lastProcessedLog.close()

    conn.close()
    ofile.close()
    logger.info("[%s] - Copying %s to root for loadBackflow as %s", correlationId, writeFile, outfile)
    shutil.copyfile(writeFile, outfile)
    logger.info("[%s] - Moving %s to completion folder %s", correlationId, writeFile, completionFolder)
    shutil.move(writeFile, completionFolder)
```

I have tried changing the writer.write(row) line to include a replace but I get an error.  Similarly, I get errors when trying to use replace with row = row.replace("\r\n", "") ... I have pasted my attempts and the corresponding errors below.

Any insights on how I can strip carriage returns / line feeds at the time they are being read from the SQL query results into the data file are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

```
# Attempt1:
writer.writerow(row).replace("\r\n", "")
# Error:
Unexpected error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

# Attempt2:
row = row.replace("\r\n", "")
#Error:
Unexpected error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

#Attempt3:
row = row.replace("\r", "")
row = row.replace("\n", "")
#Error:
Unexpected error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: How can you tell when a row belongs with the next one as opposed to being a complete row?

Answer (score 1):

[Programming by permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) is a well known antipattern... `db.cursor.fetchone()` returns a `tuple`, which - as the error message tells you - has no `replace()` method (what would be the semantic of `(1, 2, 3).replace("a string", "another string")` ?), and `csv.Writer.writerow()` return `None` (and since it would already have written the row, what would be the point of trying to modify it afterward anyway ?).

So, to make a long story short, you have two options:

1. modify **the strings in the row** before passing it to `writerow()`
2. use a csv format that allow you to escape newlines

I don't know exactly how you plan on using the generated csv, but solution #2 is still the best approach if possible - these newlines might be here for a reason - and it only requires [passing the right arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) when instanciating your `csv.Writer`.

If that's definitly not an option, solution #1 needs a bit more work, as tuples and strings are immutable:

```
def preprocess_item(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")    
    return item

def preprocess_row(row):
    return tuple(preprocess_item(item) for item in row)

def yourfunction(whatever):
    ### some code here
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    row = preprocess_row(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I think this may be the best thing. I am seeing the following error though:

Comment: Unexpected error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: '''
        While loop to read each row.  if compares row[2] (updated) against the last record processed
        '''
        latest = params #Declare 'latest' variable for consumption by while loop
        def preprocess_item(item):
            if isinstance(item, str):
                return item.replace("\r\n", "")
                #return item.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
            return item

Comment: def preprocess_row(row):
            return tuple(preprocess_item(item) for item in row)

        while row:
            if row[2] > latest:
                #row = cursor.fetchone()
                
                latest = row[2]
            logger.debug("[%s] - Writing row %s", correlationId, row)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            row = preprocess_row(row)
            writer.writerow(row)

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchone()` method returns the row as a tuple. It may contain more than one filed value depending on the table. You cannot perform the string method of replace on a tuple and that explains the error you see. I don't know the structure of the tuple returned by the `fetchone`, so I'll assume it to be the first element.

```
stripped_row = row[0].replace("\r", "")
stripped_row = stripped_row.replace("\n", "")
```